# How to scope a specific Graph API permission to a specific user or mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-calendar

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access), there is a way to scope Graph API application permissions to specific users / mailboxes with a command like this:

```
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AppId e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@contoso.com -AccessRight RestrictAccess -Description "Restrict this app to members of distribution group EvenUsers."
```

In this case, the application can use all its allowed application permissions (e.g. Mail.Send, Calendars.Read) on the members of the group EvenUsers.

But what if I want to scope a *specific permission* to a specific group? For example, the application is allowed to send mails as users in group X and is allowed to read the calendars of the users in group Y but not vice versa.

Is this possible?

Comment: As far i know, its applicable to specific users or mailboxes; not heard for groups.

Comment: Still if you think you need such granular permissions consider filing an uservoice or upvote to the related ones, so Microsoft can consider implementing it. The closest uservoice i remember is this - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39982906-applicationaccesspolicy-ability-to-define-which-sc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <s>As far i know, its applicable to specific users or mailboxes; not heard for groups</s> (see comment)
- Still if you think you need such granular permissions consider filing an uservoice or upvote to the related ones, so Microsoft can consider implementing it. The closest uservoice i remember is [this](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39982906-applicationaccesspolicy-ability-to-define-which-sc).

Comment: I agree with your second statement but not with your first. You can already scope permissions to a specific user group, it's even in the command i quoted from MS Docs. But then the selected user/mailbox/group will be the scope for EVERY application permission. I'd like to define one scope per permission. I think the uservoice you posted would solve this.

Comment: Glad to hear @PascalR. If you feel so, please upvote the uservoice!!